# jQuery slideToggle to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code:

```js
 $(function() {
      $('li').on('click', function(e)
       {
           e.stopPropagation();          
           e.preventDefault();
           alert($("a",this).data('number'));
           $(this).parent().find('#screen1').slideToggle();
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-slider">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center"> <img src="img/screen1.jpg" id="screen1">
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box">
                <p>xyz</p>
            </div>
        <div class="features-content"><ul class="fa-ul features-list">
              <li><a href="#" id="list-1" data-number="1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="list-2" data-number="2">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="list-3" data-number="3">3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="list-4" data-number="4">4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="list-5" data-number="5">5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="list-6" data-number="6">6</a></li>
        </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'd like to use slideToggle to img with id screen1. I've been thinking for a some while how to jump from this div to another. Is it possible? If I should do one, main div with img and ul list?

Comment: Please expound upon " jump from this div to another." and what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i assume you want to show different images based on the number chosen by the user. I created a plunk for you to see how that could be done https://plnkr.co/edit/JeAiitqyhg2wlgejZB1N?p=preview.

```
 $(function() {
  $('li').on('click', function(e)
   {var number=$("a",this).data('number');
       $('#screen'+number).slideDown();
       for(var i=0; i< $("#imageContainer > *").length;i++)
       {
         if(i != number)
         $('#screen'+i).slideUp();
       }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need preventDefault for li I don't think but are you looking for something like this?

```
$(function() {
      $('li').on('click', function(e) {
           var screenNum = $(this).find('a').data('number'));
           $(this).parent().find('#screen' + screenNum).slideToggle();
       });
});
```